# How do I set up a NAT Network between machines on Virtual Box that can be seen when I use airodump-ng wlan0 (wireless adapter)?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I created a NAT network called "test" and hooked up my kali linux, metasploitable, and windows 10 virtual machine. I did this by changing adapter 1 for all of them to that specific NAT network. All other adapters have been disabled. For my "test" NAT network, i left the default Network CIDR and checked only the "Supports DHCP" box. After this. I open kali linux, log in and configure my wireless adapter to monitor mode. Once in monitor mode, I then use the *airodump-ng wlan0* command to see the surrounding networks. My test network does not show up. How do I get my NAT network to show up in this situation? The reason for this is I am trying to practice pentesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing two **completely different things** – 'network' as in routing IP packets and 'network' as in broadcasting a Wi-Fi radio signal. Just because a generic "wireless router" does both at once, doesn't mean they're actually the same.

When you run airodump-ng, you see beacons transmitted by Wi-Fi access points. This has nothing to do with NAT or DHCP. To be seen in that list you need a *physical* Wi-Fi radio adapter set to "access point" mode. (You can probably switch your computer's Wi-Fi radio to this mode by enabling "Hotspot" on Windows, or by using `hostapd` on Linux.)

And vice versa, when you configure a network in VirtualBox, you're only setting up software parameters – IP routing, DHCP, firewall rules – which has absolutely nothing to do with Wi-Fi.